# Javascript regular expression: match anything up until something (if there it exists)

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am new to regular expression and this may be a very easy question (hopefully).

I am trying to use one solution for 3 kinds of string

- "45%", expected result: "45"
- "45", expected result: "45"
- "", expected result: ""

What I am trying (let the string be str):

```
str.match(/(.*)(?!%*)/i)[1]
```

This is in my head would sound like "match any instance of anything up until '%' if it is found, or else just match anything"

In firebug's head, it seems to sound more like "just match anything and completely disregard the negative lookahead". Also to make it lazy - `(.*)?` - doesn't seem to help.

Let's forget for a second that in this specific situation I am only matching numbers, so a `/\d*/` would do. I am trying to understand a general rule so that I can apply it whenever.

Anybody would be so kind to help me out?

Comment: The negative lookahead:`(?!%*)` says: _"assert that zero or more percent signs do not follow"_ This assertion can never be true because `%*` is always true! (`%*` matches nothing at all - which is _always_ true everywhere - even for an empty string.)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

How about the simpler

```
str.match(/[^%]*/i)[0]
```

Which means, match zero-or-more character, which is not a `%`.

---

Edit: If need to parse until `</a>`, then you could parse a sequence pf characters, *followed by `</a>`*, then then discard the `</a>`, which means you should use *positive* look-ahead instead of negative.

```
str.match(/.*?(?=<\/a>|$)/i)[0]
```

This means: match zero-or-more character lazily, until reaching a `</a>` or end of string.

Note that `*?` is a single operator, `(.*)?` is not the same as `.*?`.

(And [don't parse HTML with a single regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg), as usual.)

Comment: In Regular Expressions, particularly the JavaScript flavor, the `^`character means to match starting from the beginning of the reference string.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: @austincheney: That is true when `^` is used as a text anchor, but `^` has a different meaning when used within a character class, i.e. it negates the match ("anything but these chars...").

Comment: Thank you Kenny, that works. But what if "%" was "</a>"? I would like to exclude a pattern more than a single character. And just to make it clearer, "</a>" (or any pattern) might or might not be there.

Comment: Thank you Kenny, that is exactly what I was hoping to find. See my comment to Alan. Also I really appreciated that you took the time to explain it bit by bit... and Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 9):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
/(?:(?!%).)*/
```

The `.` matches any character, but only after the negative lookahead, `(?!%)`, confirms that the character is not `%`.  Note that when the sentinel is a single character like `%`, you can use a negated character class instead, for example:

```
/[^%]*/
```

But for a multi-character sentinel like `</a>`, you have to use the lookahead approach:

```
/(?:(?!</a>).)*/i
```

This is actually saying "Match zero or more characters one at a time, but if the next character turns out to be the beginning of the sequence `</a>` or `</A>`, stop without consuming it".

Comment: This is great. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks to you and Kenny now I know how to make one step at a time making sure my last step does not fall on a certain pattern `/((?!pattern).)*/` and how to make a long walk until the next character is the beginning of my pattern, or the end of a string `/.*?(?=pattern|$)/`. I think Kenny's is more what I was expecting to find, while yours is less obvious and definitely brilliant. I don't think I would have ever thought of it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way with an **exact** search string is to skip regular expressions and just use `indexOf`, e.g.:

```
// String to be searched
var s = "Here is a <a>link</a>."

// String to find
var searchString = "</a>";

// Final match
var matched = "";

var c = s.indexOf(searchString);
if (c >= 0)
{
    // Returns the portion not including the search string;
    // in this example, "Here is a <a>link". If you want the
    // search string included, add the length of the search
    // string to c.
    matched = s.substring(c);
}
```

Comment: Thank you bobby, but I was looking for a RegEx solution. What you described is what I would normally do, but in doing so I would end up reiterating this little vocabulary of mine..

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote it exactly how you said it:

```
str.match(/(^[^%]*$)|^([^%]*)%.*/i)
```

This will match any string without a '%' or the first part of a string that contains a %.
You have to get the result from the 1st or 2nd group.

EDIT: This is exactly what you want below

```
str.match(/(?:^[^%]*$)|^(?:[^%]*)(?=%)/)
```

- The ?: removes all grouping
- The ?= is a lookahead to see if the string contains %
- and [^%] matches any character that is not a %

so the regex reads match any string that doesnt contain %, OR (otherwise match) all of the characters before the first %

Answer (score 0):

to match 45, 45%, and any number of any length use this (182%, 18242, etc)

```
str.match(/([0-9]+)([%]?)/)[1];
```

if you need to match the empty string also include it as **^$**, note match("...")[1] **will be undefined for the empty string**, so you will need to test for match and then check [0] or see if [1] is undefined.

```
str.match(/([0-9]+)([%]?)|^$/)
```

if you need to match exactly two digits use **{2,2}** anchor the expression between begin and end line characters: "**^**(exp)**$**"

```
str.match(/^([0-9]{2,2})([%]?)$/)[1];
```