# regex to match ALL characters up to a certain marker

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to match all characters up to a '/'
My current regex only matches the first character of the string

```
var regex = /[^\/]/
regex.exec("something/15")
```

This will give me 's'. I have also tried

```
var regex = /.*[^\/]/
```

but it returns the whole string undelimited by '/'. I have taken a look at this other SO post as well.

[Javascript regular expression: match anything up until something (if there it exists)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584697/javascript-regular-expression-match-anything-up-until-something-if-there-it-ex)

Comment: Why not use `'First value/second value'.split('/')[0]`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use start anchor and quantifier `*` to match 0 or more characters until a `/` is found:

```
var regex = /^[^\/]*/
```

Comment: can you explain what the start anchor does and why the * comes after the exclusion clause? I would have thought you would build the pattern from the beginning up to the excluded character.

Comment: Start anchor `^` is start of input and quantifier `*` is to match 0 or more characters before a `/`

Comment: @user137717 depending on your circumstances you may want `/^[^/]+/` with `+` to match _**one** or more_ in place of `*` which matches _**zero**_ or more.

Comment: @StephenP good call Stephen P. I was getting some empty strings and used an if statement to work around, but that is very good to know.

Comment: @user137717: Yes if you don't want empty string as a match then use `/^[^\/]+/`. Though for the given input even `/^[^\/]*/` will work.

Comment: If it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although this can be accomplished with a RegEx, I would recommend using String.split() to accomplish this.

I imagine you may also want the text following the slash, so the split would allow you to access it more easily

```js
var str = 'First value/second value';
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = str.split('/')[0];
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```